# ExtendedExecutionSession is not working and uwp app is getting suspended

Tags: c#, uwp

I am using BeginExtendedExecution to avoid app suspension but it is getting revoked due to system policy.

Here is my code

```
private async void BeginExtendedExecution()
     {         
             ClearExtendedExecution();

             var newSession = new ExtendedExecutionSession();
             newSession.Reason = ExtendedExecutionReason.Unspecified;
             newSession.Description = "Raising periodic toasts";
             newSession.Revoked += SessionRevoked;
             ExtendedExecutionResult result = await newSession.RequestExtensionAsync();

             switch (result)
             {
                 case ExtendedExecutionResult.Allowed:                            
                     session = newSession;
                     break;

                 default:
                 case ExtendedExecutionResult.Denied:
                         newSession.Dispose();
                     break;
             }
     }


private async void SessionRevoked(object sender, ExtendedExecutionRevokedEventArgs args)
     {
              await Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
             {
                 switch (args.Reason)
                 {
                     case ExtendedExecutionRevokedReason.Resumed:                       
                         break;

                     case ExtendedExecutionRevokedReason.SystemPolicy:
                         break;
                 }

                 EndExtendedExecution();
             });
     }
```

Onsuspending method is getting called after few mins of app getting into background

```
 private void OnSuspending(object sender, SuspendingEventArgs e)
 {
          var deferral = e.SuspendingOperation.GetDeferral();
             deferral.Complete();
  }
```

Comment: Please refer to [ExtendedExecutionReason](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.extendedexecution.extendedexecutionreason?view=winrt-20348) Enum, it has a few limits. if you was using Unspecified reason, it has 10 minutes maximum on battery power. No limit when the device is connected to power.

Comment: Yes. I am using Unspecified reason. It's not always reproducing though. Does anything else also impact this behavior?  Also, how can we avoid this scenario of 10 mins max on battery power in laptop?

Comment: There is no way to avoid this scenario of 10 mins max on battery power in laptop. you may try use `LocationTracking` reason